# How to streaming from laptop camera to server rtmp

Tags: video, ffmpeg, webrtc, live-streaming, recordrtc

I'm looking for a solution to send data from laptop camera using browser (Javascript) to a rtmp server (like facebook live or youtube). I did researched but no luck. What I got :

1. Direct from camera to rtmp server ==> We can't do this, browser WebRTC using udp and rtmp is tcp
2. Another server as proxy ==> What I think is : browser using WebRTC and send video data to server. Server also running as a WebRTC client and receive video data, forward to ffmpeg process. ffmpeg send video data to rtmp server.

The problem is I can't find any working example for WebRTC on server (almost example use server to help 2 clients can connect together). What I need is use server as WebRTC client and get video data. 
I also take a look at RecordRTC but I only see example of upload video after stop record. I want to upload while recording (live stream)
Please help

Comment: Unfortunately "how do I" questions are typically off topic for Stack Overflow...which is a shame since they'd be great resources :|

Comment: You can try ant media server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may wish to have a look at this

https://github.com/JosePedroDias/webcam2hls

Comment: look interesting, I'll check and let you know. Thank you very much

Comment: It seems to have been discontinued... any alternative?